# Firefox 6 Orange Menu Button Does Not Show Menu

Tags: firefox

After upgrading to Firefox 6, clicking orange menu button at the top left corner will not show the menu anymore.

How can I fix this?

UPDATE: I know about the Menu Bar, I have no problems displaying it. I know I can press ALT to see "File Edit View History Bookmarks Tools Help".

My problem is the Orange Button labeled "Firefox" is not showing its own Menu of common options.

Comment: Have you tried starting Firefox in safe mode?

Comment: Yup, and the Orange Button works. So I started looking for the add-on that's causing this issue, and its: http://superuser.com/questions/324237/firefox-6-orange-menu-button-does-not-show-menu/324309#324309

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After manually disabling/restarting/testing each Firefox Add On, I found that the culprit is the gui:config Add On.

On the forum, I found that it's already reported, here: http://guiconfig.freedig.org/bugs/bugs/72-ConflictsDisables_Firefox_Button

Answer (score 0):

The menu is there under orange button *options* to get the menu bar displayed. Selecting it removes the orange button though so I guess they don't consider you might want both. Right click on the tab bar lets you disable menu and the button re-appears.

Comment: I know about the Menu Bar, I have no problems displaying it. I know I can press ALT to see "File Edit View History Bookmarks Tools Help".

My problem is the Orange Button labeled "Firefox" is not showing its own Menu of common options.